# What should I do to get higher Lighthouse score considering Google Tag Manager

Tags: lighthouse

I'm using Google Tag Manager. The problem is that Lighthouse complains that I should **Reduce unused JavaScript** and under that category shows me the Google Tag Manager script.

The point is it's not under my control. I just add that script and I'm not the one who determines its usage.

What should I do about it? How do you handle this?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using Google Tag Manager. The problem is that Lighthouse complains that I should Reduce unused JavaScript and under that category shows me the Google Tag Manager script.
>
> The point is it's not under my control. I just add that script and I'm not the one who determines its usage.

This is a common misconception in my opinion.

For a start site owners **ARE** under control of what is added via their tag managers and when that executes. See [this guide, that I contributed to](https://web.dev/tag-best-practices/) on how to improve it. If that is managed by a difference department (e.g. marketing), then I strongly encourage Developers to work with that department to understand what the tag manager is used for, and how to ensue it has as small an impact as possible. There are ways to [get greater control of a tag manager as I've blogged about before](https://www.tunetheweb.com/blog/adding-controls-to-google-tag-manager/). That is not to say that it is possible to completely address this Lighthouse audit when using tools like Google Tag Manager (even an empty container can cause this audit to flag, but usually for a very small improvement gain).

Secondly, even if you have no power over the tag manager, that does not mean a performance analysis tool like Lighthouse should ignore it. It runs various audits on a site and highlights things that could potentially be improved. To ignore things, simply because they are difficult to fix is not the right model in my opinion. And even though Lighthouse and Google Tag Manager are both run by Google, that doesn't means Lighthouse will give Google tools a free pass (and nor should it!).

Thirdly, the "OPPORTUNITIES" and "DIAGNOSTICS" sections of Lighthouse provide just that - opportunities that *may* improve website performance or diagnostics that *may* aid you in fixing performance issues. They do not always **HAVE** to be followed. It could be that the impact of them is small, or the effort and complexity to resolve them is more than you feel comfortable with, or simply that the business benefit of having this is worth more than the performance cost. These are decisions a site owner must take. Lighthouse gives an estimate of the performance gain from addressing that audit - so you need to ask yourself if this issue is something you need to look at, or whether to accept that and look at other issues instead.

So, if you don't want them to flag in Lighthouse CI, because this is creating noise for something that is not a priority to fix, then you can [configure Lighthouse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/main/docs/configuration.md) not to highlight this particular audit (for example with `'unused-javascript': 'off'`, by allowing one large script not to fail the audit with `'unused-javascript': ['error', {maxLength: 1}]`). This is not an option in tools like [PageSpeed Insights](https://pagespeed.web.dev/) or running Lighthouse in Chrome DevTools but, as I say above, to me it is valid to highlight these potential issues rather than ignore them.

Comment: Please don't post answers that promote your own website

Comment: I've edited my answer to note that I contributed to, or wrote, both posts. However, I don't think a link for further information, related to the question asked, is a bad thing as long as it is useful supplemental information that isn't directly required by the answer, which should be, and is, supplied in the answer here. See this meta post for discussion on it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273211/2144578